# DrawNode not working when number of vertices exceeds 65,536 on android device

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

Currently, I am working on some drawing app using Cocos2d-x v3.3.
When user touches on screen, the app draws line by connecting the points from the touches.

To draw lines, I use `DrawNode::drawPolygon`.
When the number of vertices hits 65,536, it does not draw correctly. I took a look at the code in DrawNode. It uses glDrawArrays to draw polygons. Is there any limit of vertices for glDrawArrays?

It works fine on my iPhone5S and iOS simulators,
but not on my Android device SC-05D.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you are using glDrawArrays then OpenGL itself doesn't specify a limit, but sometimes the hardware does. Generally, keeping under 64k is a good idea (split your draw calls if you need to go over).

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure but I believe it is a result of `GLsizei`. I recommend you log the value of `_bufferCount`. Check if this will go back to 0 when the problem appears. If this is the case, then you can conclude that on your test device `GLsizei` is a 16-bit unsigned integer. Please check and let me know!

Comment: I checked the value in _bufferCount, but it does not go back to 0 when it hits over 65,536. I will try to split draw calls as raveesh said to solve the issue! Thank you.